# How do I make an exe file from a python code under Ubuntu?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I'm using Ubuntu 16 64-bit and python 3.5

I made a program on python and I want to distribute it as an EXE for Windows users.

The program I made depends on pandas and matplotlib

I downloaded PyInstaller.tar.gz and extracted it, but I can't find any clear info on how to make make an EXE.

I tried

```
python ../PyInstaller/pyinstaller.py --onefile ../Project/program.py
```

But it creates a sub folder with a lot of files and none of them are exe

Comment: `python ../PyInstaller/pyinstaller.py --onefile ../Project/program.py`

Comment: try putting the `--onefile` argument *after* the script, then go look in the "dist" folder